# When someone says "I'm on the 10th episode of the show," do they mean they just finished the 9 or they've started to watch the 10th?

Tags: prepositions

When someone says *I'm on the 10th episode of the show*, do they mean they just finished the 9 or they've started to watch the 10th? Also, is there any difference in meaning between *I'm on the 10th episode* and *I'm at the 10th episode*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that it **could** mean either. The balance of probability is that, by saying *I'm on* means they are in the process of watching.

In my opinion the difference between *I'm on* and  *I'm at* is that *I'm on* implies that you are in the process of watching whilst *I'm at* implies that you have reached, but not necessarily started to view, the episode. However the difference is blurred and the two phrases could be used interchangeably.

If you really wanted to make the distinction then it would be better to say *I'm about to start viewing episode 10*  or *I'm watching episode 10*